# Coding to an interface in C

Tags: c, interface

How can you program to an interface in C as you would in Go?

Go code:

```
package measure
type Weighable interface {
    Weigh() float64
}
func Weight(w Weighable) float64 {
    return w.Weigh()
}
```

Now any type which has a Weigh() method that returns a float64 is considered "Weighable".

```
package planet 
type Info struct {
    volume float
    density float
}
func (own *Info) Weigh() float64 {
    return own.volume * own.density
}
```

So because a planet is Weighable, I can Weigh() it.

```
package main
import "measure", "planet"

func main() {
    Earth := &planet.Info{1097509500, 5.51}
    EarthWeight = measure.Weight(Earth) 
}
```

Now anything, a person or a subatomic particle, may be weighed differently, but can be invoked using the same code, **measure.Weight(Person)** or **measure.Weight(subatomicParticle)**

---

Question:

Header files, which define function signatures, seems to be the right way to proceed, but what about the function which takes an interface as an argument?  Can this be done in C, or is there a better way?

Comment: -1? Any Helpful tips, corrections etc?  Seems like a valid question with useful replies, and what you're telling me is I should just delete it?  I don't understand.

Comment: No, maybe it just means that the reader thinks it's not useful or any other motivation for the downvote. But it is indeed a valid question (*perhaps, not a great question*) but valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. That's not how [c](/questions/tagged/c) programs are meant to be. If you want object oriented capabilities the closest thing to [c](/questions/tagged/c) is [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you can write `class`es with pure virtual *methods*, they will not need an implementation in the class where you declare them as pure virtual

```
public:
    virtual int pure_virtual_method() = 0;
    //                                ^ this means PURE VIRTUAL
```

then any class that inherits from this class MUST implement `pure_virtual_method()`.

This is exactly what an *interface* is for example as understood in the *java* language. You have a skeleton of a class with predefined but unimplemented method and you derive classes from that skeleton being forced to provide implementations to some methods. This is really elegant and is almost the only thing I love about [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

**Note**: there is a Object Oriented [c](/questions/tagged/c) library I know of [glib](/questions/tagged/glib), but it's really cumbersome and I never really liked the way they make [c](/questions/tagged/c) "*object oriented*". Inheritance is possible but it's too complicated for my taste.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can implement a funtion table like this ([in fact, OLE technologies are implemented using this principle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733)):

```
typedef struct tagOBJECT OBJECT;

// This is the interface

typedef struct tagIVTABLE {

  int (*getData)(OBJECT* This);
  void (*setData)(OBJECT* This, int i);

}IVTABLE;

typedef struct tagOBJECT {

  IVTABLE* lpVtbl;

  int data;

} OBJECT;

int someGetFunction(OBJECT* This) {

  return This->data;
}

void someSetFunction(OBJECT* This, int i) {
    This->data = i;
}

int main(void)
{


  IVTABLE Vtbl;  

  OBJECT obj;
  OBJECT obj2;

  Vtbl.getData = someGetFunction;
  Vtbl.setData = someSetFunction;

 // You would code this in a constructor function
 obj.lpVtbl = &Vtbl;
 obj2.lpVtbl = &Vtbl;


 obj.lpVtbl->setData(&obj, 7);

 printf("\n%d", obj.lpVtbl->getData(&obj));

 obj2.lpVtbl->setData(&obj2, 77);

 printf("\n%d", obj2.lpVtbl->getData(&obj2));

 return 0;
}
```

Notice how the functions must have a pointer to the approproiate object ... C++ compilers generate this hidden parameter in instance methods and the keyword this refers to that parameter. This example is just to illustrate the principle. Hope it will help :-)

Comment: There is no way to enforce reimplementing the methods and IMHO this makes [tag:c] code hard to understand or use. There is no reason to try and use object oriented concepts in a non-object oriented language. Also, the most important thing about an interface is missing here. You can't derive a class from a shallow base class where methods are not implemented but are basically placeholders that just serve one purpose "*ensure that the method exists*", but their implementation is left to the derived class.

Comment: Note that this syntax `obj.lpVtbl->setData(&obj, 7);` is hard to deal with, whereas the [tag:c] way `v_tbl_set_data(&obj, 7)` is much simpler and you HAVE TO pass the object anyway so having the function defined in the object just, increases the object size for no good reason.

Comment: iharob ... I agree with you; in C, one HAS to implement object-oriented principles and everything is more tedious and harder to understand as you pointed out. This was just to answer the question.

Comment: I understand and I think you did a great job in explaining that and the fact that after all [tag:c++] compilers need to generate similar code in order for objects to make sense. But you don't need to worry about what [tag:c++] compilers really do except if you're concerned about things like performance (*for example when using templates it's useful to know what the compiler will do*). Anyway, I didn't mean to say it's not a good or valid answer. Just a comment that seems to be missing in your answer.

Comment: iharob, indeed I should have pointed it out in my answer. I appreciate your input as well as an honest discussion :-)

Comment: But notice that the original question wasn't about c vs c++. It was about c vs Go. I think the interesting point is how interfaces in Go are different from "interfaces" in c++. How the compiler deduces that type planet.Info can be converted to interface.